# How to replicate the effect of the ScalingFunctions option?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have a plot with potentially non-default `ScalingFunctions`, and an Epilog that adds a point, e.g.:

```
scaling = "Log";
data = {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};
scaled[{x_,y_}, "Log"] := {x, Log[y]};
ListPlot[
   data, ImageSize -> Medium,
   ScalingFunctions -> scaling,
   Epilog->{ Style[Red], Point[scaled[{3,10},scaling]] }
]
```

It's tedious to define the variants of `scaled` function every time I need to use a new plot scaling.

Is there a better way to add plot elements (extra points, annotations, etc) that scale the same as the data of the plot? Something like `MainBody` (after `Prolog`, before `Epilog`) that would be scaled the same as the data, or some implementation detail that could be reused?

I didn't dig in the Plot source code, since I would like to know if there are better options than finding implementation details on my own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I can appreciate the desire for some sort of automatic rescaling in the Epilog, it does seem like a lot to expect. I might be wrong, but I don't really think it was designed to be able to inspect the plot as much more than just the final graphics. But also, if your special points have the same scale as the data, then why not just plot them directly?

```
data = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
specials = {{3, 10}}; (* I'm assuming there could be several of these. *)

ListPlot[{data, specials}, ScalingFunctions -> "Log", PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Red}]
```

Or if you use an explicit scaling function instead of the special string specification, it's at least easier to do the scaling in the Epilog:

```
data = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
scale = Log;
specials = {{3, 10}};
ListPlot[data, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {scale, InverseFunction[scale]}, 
  Epilog -> {Red, Point[MapAt[scale, #, -1]] & /@ specials}, 
  PlotRange -> {All, 10}]
```